# Need an Alert confirming the action has been performed once button is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Webapp that functions as designed
All I want is to add a pop up confirming users action

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return output;
}

function mycalSub() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(
    'ABC@xyz.com',
    { color: CalendarApp.Color.BLUE });
  Logger.log('Subscribed to the calendar "%s".', calendar.getName());
}
```

[Google App Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znpCb.png)

[Index file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yNW1.png)

Comment: Posting code is images is useless.  The point of creating [mcve] is so that we can copy it and try to create the problem ourselves thus making it easier for us to find thet problem or resolve the issue and thus help you.  Most of us that volunteer here are fairly good at debuggging out code or we wouldn't be doing this.  Do yourself a favor and learn how to post code using SO guidelines which were created to help you help us help you. All you need to know is on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Posting Screen images of tabs/sheets can be helpful but also posting the sheets data as a table is even more helpful because it gives us real data to deal with.

Comment: Do you want the pop to appear on the webapp? If so I've used I've used JQueryUI dialogs they're pretty easy to use.  Generally, when a webapp opens a spreadsheet it only opens on the server so there is no user interface available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript methods that are accessible from the clientside of your WebApp

**Index.html**

```
<button class="button" onclick="popup()"> Failsafe Calendar </button>
```

```
<script>
    function popup() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
            alert("mycalSub finished successfully!!");
        }).mycalSub();
    }
</script>
```

#### Edit:

- Added `withSuccessHandler` as per Cooper's suggestion to verify if it finished successfully.

#### Reference:

- [JavaScript Popup Boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)
- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: If you did it using a `.withSuccessHandler()` then that would also help to guarantee that the server function finished without an error.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion @Cooper. I modified my answer above to incorporate that. As for what happened yesterday, I actually didn't pay it any attention. I do understand your frustration due to how I did phrase my answer. I do appreciate the criticism and accept your apology.